# What's the cost of converting a sequential collection into a parallel one, against creating it from scratch

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing, parallel-collections

according [to the official docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) there are two options to create parallel collections:

1)

```
// There's a little bug here, doesn't matter for the sake of the question
import scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray
val pv = new ParVector[Int]
```

2)

```
val pv = Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).par
```

Now, what are the differences? Does exist any performance penalty when I convert it from a simple sequential collection?

What would you do if you've to create a bit parallel collection (say, several thousand elements), would you create it from scratch or convert it?

Thank you guys!

**EDIT:**

As @oxbow_lakes says there's a piece of docs that focus on this topic, but i'm trying to get "experienced advices". I mean, what would YOU do if you have to read a big collection from a DB, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the collection. `Vector` is basically free, `ParVector` is just a wrapper around the vector. Same for `Arrays`. Others, e.g. `List`, will have to be completely copied in a different structure, more amenable to parallelism. And then copied back to a new list if you want your result to be a List too.

You may have a look at [this brand new guide on the scala documentation site](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html), section Creating a parallel collection.

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation for the `par` method says:

> *For most collection types, this method creates a new parallel collection by **copying all the elements**. For these collection, par takes **linear time** [...]*
>
> *Specific collections (e.g. `ParArray` or `mutable.ParHashMap`) override this default behaviour by creating a parallel collection which shares the same underlying dataset. For these collections, par takes constant **or sublinear** time.*

That is, in general the operation in O(n), except when using the **mutable** collections `ParArray` and `ParHashMap`, where it is less that O(n) - but possibly not constant time.

Comment: +1 Thanks @oxbow_lakes I've read that, but I was looking for some advice given experience. For example, what would YOU do if you've to create a big collection (say, for example, reading it from a DB).

Comment: I'm not sure if you are claiming only mutable collections enjoy this benefit or not, but that is certainly not true. `List` needs copying, true, but `Vector` does not, for example.